# Username Routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying make a project in which */username* gets redirected to that username's profile. How can I make this happen?

Comment: [This is a good place to get started](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The route would be: `"get /:username", to: "users#profile"`

You would change `users#profile` to whatever your controller action is called.

You need to make sure to put this **at the end of your routes**. Otherwise it will *intercept all your routes*.

For example, don't do the following:

```
get "/:username", to: "users#profile"
get "/foo", to: "pages#bar"
```

Because you will never be able to reach the `pages#bar` endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

Problem with the previous answer is that anything that doesn't match in routes would be routed to `users#profile`.

Alternatively, and to solve that issue, you can create a dynamic router, like this:

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      User.all.each do |user|
        puts "Routing #{user.name}"
        get "/#{user.name}", :to => "users#profile", defaults: { id: user.id }
      end
    end
  end

  def self.reload
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

Then on the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to not_found_path unless @user
  end
end
```

And to actually generate the routes at server start:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'not_found' => 'somecontroller#not_found', as: :not_found
  DynamicRouter.load
end
```

Finally to reload routes when a user is added/updated:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_save :reload_routes

  def reload_routes
    DynamicRouter.reload
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!